# Inverting continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ in one variable retains continuity of other?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A, B, C$ be intervals of real numbers and let $f: A \times B \to C$ be continuous in both arguments and assume that for each $b \in B$, the function $f_b: A \to C$ is a bijection.

Define $g:C \times B \to A$ to be the inverse of this function for each $b \in B$, i.e. $g(c,b) = f_b^{-1}(c)$.

We know by the continuous inverse theorem that $g$ is continuous in $c$ but is $g$ continuous in $b$?